# OrientDB - Sorting a cluster by a property

Tags: java, api, orientdb

How do you sort a cluster using java API? In other words, how do you do

```
List<ODocument> results = db.query(new OSQLSynchQuery<ODocument>("SELECT * FROM FilteredCompounds ORDER BY cidScore DESC"));
```

with JAVA API??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that with Java API without SQL.

Comment: Thanks. Why doesn't following query work?? new OSQLSynchQuery<ODocument>("SELECT @rid as realRID,cidScore FROM FilteredCompounds ORDER BY cidScore DESC")); When I ran this SQL query on the console, it worked fine.